# cracked ceramics

Tags: node-editor

I have been trying to do in blender a material, procedurally that looks like 
 cracked ceramics, something such as:

https://www.pinterest.com/pin/323907398201320149/

So far this is as far as I reached:

[image]

there are some lines that are too thick! Also would be nice to make the lines not perfectly continuous but with some parts fading away like in the reference image.

Below there is what I have used so far.
[image]

Any suggestion on what to improve?

thank you so much, 
best regards :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this shader, it's a bit to complex to explain. But you can edit the nodes in the frames and fiddle around.

[image]

[image: Render]

[image: Node Setup]

Comment: Great! thank you so much :)I have done this with the material you provided and some adjustments :) best regards Luis [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/matr1.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/matr1.jpg)